# Opacity in Chrome after CSS3 keyframe

Tags: css, google-chrome

Opacity changes on hover event don't work after keyframe animation is finished. It doesn't work in Chrome only; other browsers are just fine.

```
.part_jedinacni {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -webkit-animation:showit 0.5s forwards;           
    -webkit-animation-delay:2s;
    opacity:0;
}


@-webkit-keyframes showit {
    0% {opacity:0;}
    100% {opacity:1;}
}

.part_jedinacni:hover {
    opacity:1 !important;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using animation for this? 
Set `.part_jedinacni{opacity:0;}`, 
and `.part_jedinacni:hover{opacity: 1; -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease; transition: opacity, 0.5s, ease;}`

Comment: I use it because there is 9 elements that shows one after another (same animation but different delay)